# Facebook iOS SDK 3.2 Reopen Session Always Fails

Tags: ios, facebook, session, sdk

Basically I went through this page and implement my Facebook login.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/

Next I tried to reopen the session when user opens up the app again with this:

```
[appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO];

//The method is:

- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
        @"email", 
        @"user_likes",
        nil];
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                             state:state
                                                             error:error];
                                     }];
}
```

But FBSessionState always comes 0:

```
/*! One of two initial states indicating that no valid cached token was found */
    FBSessionStateCreated                   = 0,
```

I tried almost everything, storing and restoring tokendata with FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy, but none of it worked. If I call

```
[appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
```

and display LoginUI the session starts, but I don't want to display LoginUI everytime. Can you help me?

Comment: When you said you tried to store/restore data with FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy, you mean that you set it to FBSessionManualTokenCachingStrategy, with the appropriate data (you can test via the class method isValidTokenInformation: in FBSessionManualTokenCachingStrategy.  Once you set the token, is the session still in the 'FBSessionStateCreated' state or does it change to the 'FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded' state?